# Cannot Join a Domain on VM

Tags: domain, vmware-server, vmware-player

I have installed Windows 2003 server R2 on a VM. This VM is running on Windows XP PRO. When i try to make this XP Pro PC join the domain on the VM it tries to locate the server and gives me the following error message " The specified network name is no longer available", despite the fact that i can still see this domain on my network.

can anyone help with this please.

This is the very first time i am trying connecting a client to a VM server so hope am not doing anything wrong..

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check the DNS setting for the PC and make sure that it is either pointing to the Domain Controller as the DNS server, or pointing to a DNS server that forwards to the domain's DNS server.

Comment: pointed the DNS to the DC's IP Address, and as alternate DNS i put the DNS specified on the server DNS still no luck.. :(

Comment: you should only use one - you need to resolve _tcp.<domain-name>:

try `nslookup _tcp.<domain-name>` - when this command answers with the IP address, you'll be set.